# Pipes were frozen-cold water coming from hot

Tags: plumbing, pipe

Our hot water pipe was frozen in our garage. We got it thawed out and for fifteen seconds there was a burst of hot water now it is only cold water. Could it be that the water is still cold from the ice and it will get hot as the ice is fully melted and my hot water tank catches up or what could be the issue?

Comment: Is the water heater in the garage?